# NuGet DependentUpon files

Tags: wpf, nuget

Let's say I have a WPF Control that I want to deploy as source code transformation via NuGet.

The control has 2 files associated with it: UserControl.xaml.cs and UserControl.xaml.

When I deploy it via NuGet I get the files in the target project, but they don't have the hierarchy structure in the solution explorer.  This is due to the fact that NuGet does not know how to add the DependentUpon property in the .csproj file.

Is there a workaround?  Is this feature in the roadmap of NuGet?

Thanks 
Tal

Comment: I have no straight answer for this nor any hands on experience but you should probably be able to manipulate the project directly using the projects DTE object. Like in the Package Manager Console.

Comment: PM> ((get-project).ProjectItems | where {$_.Name -eq "UserControl.xaml"}).ProjectItems

Answer (score 3):

The answer is Powershell, specifically the Install.ps1 file that will execute automatically upon install if placed within a /tools folder in your NuGet package. Here's code that should do the trick:

```
    param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

    $buildProject = @([Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection]::GlobalProjectCollection.GetLoadedProjects($project.FullName))[0]  

    $file = $buildProject.Xml.Items | Where Include -eq "UserControl.xaml.cs"
    $propertyToEdit = $file.Metadata | Where Name -eq "DependentUpon"

    if (!$propertyToEdit)
    {
        $file.AddMetaData("DependentUpon", "UserControl.xaml") | Out-Null
    }

    $project.Save()
```

You may not see the change immediately in the Visual Studio interface, but if you unload/reload or close/open the project, you'll see it.

Comment: Brilliant answer, just one small error. The line "$item.AddMetaData("DependentUpon", "UserControl.xaml") | Out-Null" should read "$file.AddMetaData("DependentUpon", "UserControl.xaml") | Out-Null".